# Removing acoustic echo in an Android mic to speaker app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an android app which takes input from the headset mic when connected and output it to the earphones. The problem is I am getting an echo while streaming the live mic data to the earphones. I am using AudioRecorder class in Android and I read that in some mobiles the internal "ACOUSTIC ECHO CANCELLATION" is not working in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use a conference microphone/speaker with built-in noise cancelling.

Android implement noise cancelling API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/NoiseSuppressor.html)

Comment: i tried it but gives error "cannot resolve symbol NoiseSuppressor" while importing package